# Error while launching the application on device

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am getting this error while launching the application on device:

```
Error launching remote program: No such file or directory (/private/var/mobile/Applications/3E6A33F8-52EE-4A0B-AB9F-A122B7C42045/Test.app/Test)
```

Comment: Answer below, though popular, did not work for me.  See my answer here: [Xcode 4 Error: Error Starting Executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607154/xcode-4-error-error-starting-executable/7354557#7354557)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

First try restarting Xcode. If it doesn't work, then try hard reset of your device.
This happens to me when I change the bundle identifier of my app.

Comment: Xcode restart should be enough. Make sure you quit and reopen xcode, not just close a project. :-P

Comment: All I had to do was restart XCode4.  I didn't have to restart the device.

Comment: restart XCode did the trick, great!
PS: I also encountered this problem after changed the bundle ID.

Comment: Yes, all I had to do was restart xcode as well, and as springrider said, I recently changed the Bundle ID, which may have something to do with it.

Comment: Restarting xcode did the trick, thanks :) - I wonder why it never crossed my mind to try a xcode restart!

Comment: can't believe it. restarting the xcode worked.. Turns out this could happen after changing bundle identifier. Thank

Comment: @VanDuTran because it's kinda sad in this day and age that we still have to restart Xcode (or any tool) for no justifiable reason. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With XCode 5 beta, an Hard reset of the device was needed to solve the problem.

Comment: How did you initiate the hard reset?

Comment: Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings

Answer (score 1):

What finally fixed it for me was restarting the device (after doing everything else everyone recommends here, here [Xcode 4 Error: Error Starting Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607154/xcode-4-error-error-starting-executable/7354557#7354557) here [Xcode suddenly stopped running project on hardware: "Could not launch xxx.app: .. No such file.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) and here [Xcode Developer Preview: Cannot Run on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651697/xcode-developer-preview-cannot-run-on-device)

Answer (score 1):

If just restarting Xcode and the iPhone does not help, look at your provisioning profiles.  Shift-Command-2 brings it up from within Xcode.  You can then select the device and then provisioning profiles within that.  Deleting your profiles (mine had numerous similar-looking entries created by Xcode) and then restarting Xcode and the iPhone clears the problem.

If your app is a background app you will need to manually delete the app before deploying the new version.  For example, say you've an iBeacon aware app, and mark yourself as a background consumer of Bluetooth Low Energy then the OS keeps some record of your app even when it is not running.  This record is not properly cleared out when a new version is deployed (iOS 7.0.4).  That will cause the reported error, as well as hang the debug and deployment protocol to the handset.  The handset will need a restart.

A hack to sidestep the problem is to change the bundle id of your app to something that the phone has not seen.  Then it deploys to the handset as a newly seen app avoiding problems from references to the old app.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by trying to deploy a target to a device which is not supported e.g. iPad app to iPhone. I got this cryptic message when I forgot to switch it to Universal app.

Answer (score 0):

It also happen when your Deployment Target is higher than your Device.

Lower it and it may work.

(thanks to Ian Kershaw, whose made me look around this field)

Answer (score 0):

What finally fixed for me was **CLEANING**(Command + Shift + K) the Xcode project...