# I changed application identifier in app-Info.plist and then I changed it back and can't run it on my device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

It runs on simulator but on my device it does not. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What happens when you try to built it on your device?

Comment: Look at the device errors in organizer.

Comment: Have you tried the solution to: [Xcode 4 Error: Error Starting Executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607154/xcode-4-error-error-starting-executable/7354557#7354557) ?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I did not get any error messages. The problem was solved as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the application from the device first. Then clean, build and deploy again.

If that does not work, quit XCode and bring it back up again.

You may also have to open Organizer and check that the device has the provisioning profile that was used to sign the app.