# Cannot Install into iPhone Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, llvm

I've got an Xcode project that I've been working on over the past few weeks.

I just made some changes to an embedded framework that I'm working on (recompiled, to be specific) now, however, I am unable to launch the application in the simulator.

The app hangs on "Attaching to [app name]," if I have a debugger on. If I don't have a debugger on, Xcode just says the app has finished running.

There is no icon installed on the device.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Restarted
- Reset simulator
- Clean and build
- Deleted derrived data

I cannot install onto a device either, but then I get an error:

```
Error launching remote program: No such file or directory (/Users/peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/x-gtwuuwmavjonyrcxjmpcletdpyjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/x.app/x).
```

Comment: Are you getting any build errors?

Comment: If there were build errors it wouldn't launch... is your disk full? (long shot)

Comment: @alan None, not even a warning.

Comment: Did you change the bundle identifier recently?

Comment: @sapta No, but out of interest what would that have to do with it?

Comment: @Peter: because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840606/error-while-launching-the-application-on-device happened to me once earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, what worked was installing another app in the sim (just launched another project and ran it) and then launching the other app in the sim.

I'm not sure what the issue was, but I tried it on two computers and it was hanging on each, so it was related to the project rather than the simulator. There's an issue to think about...