# Application not automatically launching in device and getting error on xcode

Tags: ios, device, xcode4.5, launch

I'm getting a weird bug on Xcode 4.5. When i tried to run my application on Ipad 2 from xcode with iOS 6, I'm getting this error.

[image: Error]

I done the following methods to run the application, but no luck.

1. Cleaned the project and run
2. Restarted the device
3. Restarted xcode

I have a valid certificate in my machine and the application is installing on the device but it's not launching automatically. What could be the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By any chance have you set your Build Configuration to Distribution / Release. Setting Build Config to Debug fixed this issue for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode suddenly stopped running project on hardware: "Could not launch xxx.app: .. No such file.."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is really annoying. This error happens in a number of different situations. Sometimes restarting the Xcode, fixes the problem. If not, follow these steps:

Disconnect your device.

Delete the app from your device.

Quit Xcode (Do not just simply close the window, quit it)

Delete derived data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-gbrvhlvwmpiobxdujegtghggrffp - or something like that)

Now start Xcode once again, connect device and run the project. It should work fine.

from DhilipSiva [blog](http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html)

Comment: Just wanted to add this just worked after Xcode failed to run on my iPhone (worked on simulator) with the following error: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).