# Project not running in apple device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application not automatically launching in device and getting error on xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373994/application-not-automatically-launching-in-device-and-getting-error-on-xcode)

Hi want to run my `iOS` app on device . I have the provision profile, but whenever I run my app on device it shows the following error:

```
No such file or directory (/Users/varun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myproj-axtuxgmraelfbkczsttvahwpsmzj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myproj.app/Myproj)
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: I dont know what exactly went wrong, but maybe you missed a step. Here is good tutorial for setting everything up for testing it on your device : [link -->](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

Comment: Are you using any external library?

Answer (score 1):

Quit `Xcode` and try to run it. It'll work fine. Still if you've problem delete `Derived data`, open your `organizer` and goto `projects` tab, select your `Project` and Delete `Derived data` which is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same scenario before.

1. Disconnected device.
2. Deleted application
3. Cleaned my project.
4. Connected and installed my app

After that it worked perfectly for me.