# error while launching app on iPod

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

Could not launch “TapBlackJack”
No such file or directory (/Users/nabeel.ahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBlackJackPOC-fxpktgxemrwknacpmlawwnlnyyxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TapBlackJack.app/TapBlackJack)

Following error comes on Xcode while i will run app on my ipod but it runs perfect on simulator.
**NOTE**
Dont say that delete derived data,quit xcode , restart ipod, i tried every thing

Comment: please check my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373994/application-not-automatically-launching-in-device-and-getting-error-on-xcode

Comment: yes, this happens if some thing went wrong when file created while building the project.Try above solution

Comment: Just shut xcode down and then load it back up. Had the exact same issue this morning.

Comment: please see the question carefully..". NOTE Dont say that delete derived data,quit xcode , restart ipod, i tried every thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in info.plist. in older xCode "Required device capabilities" is of dictionary type where as in newer Xcode(4.5.1) it is of array type.

Answer (score 0):

Just move that folder of your application to  somewhere else , then quit xcode and start again.

let me know it is working or not my friend.

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: NO my friend.same problem:(