# Could not lauch a application in Ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode suddenly stopped running project on hardware: “Could not launch xxx.app: .. No such file..”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app)
>   [Application not automatically launching in device and getting error on xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373994/application-not-automatically-launching-in-device-and-getting-error-on-xcode)

I recently changed the name of my application in xcode. After changing the name I couldnt run my application in tablet. I can run my application in simulator but I couldnt run it on my IPAD.

Am getting the following error.

[image: Error Message]

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you deleted the previous app with the previous name? Hope it may help you.

Comment: @sanjitshaw Yes I have done that. Still it doest work

Comment: Please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373994/application-not-automatically-launching-in-device-and-getting-error-on-xcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning (Product->Clean) your application and then run it.

Hope it helps you..

EDIT :-

Try two things

1. Delete application with same bundle identifier
2. Delete your derived data.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't. I even restarted my Xcode.. Thot too doesnt

Comment: Have you deleted application from Simulator with that bundle id?

Comment: Two Application having different name and with same bundle id on simulator does not run

Comment: My application works on simulator. Its not working in my device. Should I need to delete it in simulator for this?

Comment: on sorry on your device, is there any application with same bundle id?

Comment: No I deleted all my previous apps!!

Comment: Then delete your derived data of your application

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart your device.
2. Go ahead and delete the XCWorkpace. I've done this quite a lot of times. Following are the steps:

   1. Close your project in Xcode. Navigate into your xcodeproj package
      (either through Terminal, or in Finder by right-clicking and
      selecting "Show Package Contents")
   2. Delete your XCWorkpace.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

When you are launching the app in iPad for debugging, you must use developer certificate. if you use distribution certificate you may get this kind of error.

1. Go to the build settings
2. In code signing part there will be code signing identity.
3. In which there will be debug and release
4. In debug you must use developer certificate.

Comment: No I dont have a distribution certificate. I have a developer certificate. And I didnt mentioned it, before changing the app name it was working fine on my device

Comment: delete the app from ipad and restart it