# xcode 4.5 app can not run in device No such a file directory error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi now i am developing ios app with Restkit frame work its working perfectly in simulator. But not running in device (with debug as well as Release). It gives the following error

**Could not launch "xxxxx.app"
No such file or dirctory (/Users/threesea001/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX/Build/products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXX.app/XXXX)**

I tried restart Xcode, Device, mac also. Still not fixed. I tried Clear DerivedData folder.

Please help any one. I tried more than 5 times above

Comment: Please check the answer for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373994/application-not-automatically-launching-in-device-and-getting-error-on-xcode

Comment: Try to Clean. Cmd+Shift+K

Comment: i done it many times.