# XCode "Could not launch Game Name, no such file or directory..."

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the dreaded

```
Could not launch game name, no such file or directory (/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Name-erqxxxxxxxxxgesgegesgesg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Game Name.app/Game Name)
```

When I try and run the game on my iPhone. It builds/runs fine in the simulator, and the weird thing is it gives me a build successful msg even when trying to run on the phone, but then that error msg pops up afterwards.

Obviously I've googled this issue, and I've tried the suggestion here http://dhilipsiva.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file.html But I'm still getting the same issue.

I checked and my phone is using the latest version of iOS (6.1.x) and XCode is targeting the latest version of iOS as well.

Can't find any other reason for the cause. I did actually take the an original xcode project and changed the name of it to my current name, maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Hello Phil. The link you shared points to my blog. If you managed to solve this some how, please let me know so that I can update my post as required.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I seemed to have found the issue, it was this (found on here [Xcode suddenly stopped running project on hardware: "Could not launch xxx.app: .. No such file.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app?rq=1))

"I found out what it was - while adding device capabilities to the info.plist I had somehow added a new row but not given it a value. – Amino acids"

I had a "required device capabilities" with one item which was "gameKit" but for some reason that was causing it not to work. I've tested similar projects that required gamekit on the phone before and it worked fine. Unless I typed in gameKit incorrectly or something. Anyway that seems to be working.