# Xcode/Cocos2d-x "Could not inspect application package" error randomly alternates with "${EXECUTABLE_NAME} does not exist"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to run my Cocos2d-x app built in Xcode 5.0.2 on a 4th generation iPod Touch running iOS 6.1.5. I don't have any third party libraries in the project yet, other than Cococs2d-x.

When I hit run, the behavior is inconsistent. Xcode builds the whole project without a hitch, but then gives me one of two errors at random. It doesn't strictly alternate, and it isn't tied to whether it's a clean build. It's just a coin toss.

Sometimes, I get not one, but two `Could not inspect the application package.` errors.

Sometimes, on the other hand, Xcode gives me this error:

```
The Info.plist for application at /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app specifies a CFBundleExecutable of ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}, which does not exist
```

I've found several reports of similar errors around the internet, but they usually say it specifies an executable of "(null)", and their solutions don't work for me. The most popular solution is, frustratingly, to set `CFBundleExecutable` (AKA "Executable File") to `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` in my Info.plist, which it is.

Any ideas? This is really weird.

UPDATE: Okay, I set Executable File to my literal product name, and now I'm down to the two "Could not inspect the application package." errors. The other error no longer comes up. That's some progress, anyway...

Comment: Check here once u may get solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456312/xcode-suddenly-stopped-running-project-on-hardware-could-not-launch-xxx-app

Comment: If you post your info.plist it might help to determine if there's a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
CFBundleExecutable ${PRODUCT_NAME}
```

in your info.plist

Sometimes deleting the ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and manually putting it in works also. It sounds as if there's some corruption going on with the build and it's ignoring the parameter.

Comment: *When building an XCode project, I do `Product > Clean` (Shift-Command K), followed by `Build` (Command-B), then `Run` (Command-R)