# Xcode Developer Preview: Cannot Run on Device

Tags: ios, xcode5

When trying to run any project in an Xcode Developer Preview (Xcode 5 DP6 in my case), the app is not started and the following error message appears:

> Could not launch "" - No such file or directory (/private/var/mobile/Applications/741F0826-E354-4E13-9CC3-0FB3A66E8798/.app)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple in my case, in Terminal just execute

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/
```

with the path for the currently used Xcode Developer Preview.

Do not forget to switch back when developing on the previous stable Xcode version again - especially when archiving for AppStore submit.

Comment: Maybe you also need to reconnect the device and close other Xcode instances.

Comment: I use both version without problem, and without the need to switch between them. I uploaded a new app just few days ago. Strange

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. It was the only way I could get it to work. I tried a lot of other workarounds like restarting Xcode, restarting OS X, restarting my devices, resetting my devices, cleaning the project, removing derived data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, I did following things to sort out my problem:-

1) Changed "don't sign" and "iPhone distribution" to my valid developer provisioning profile in Xcode's build setting.

2) Quit Xcode.

3) Uninstalled App from device.

4) Unplugged device.

5) Plugged in device.

6) Ran Xcode

7) Built and Ran App.

Thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

This has a very simple solution (works on every Xcode so it's not NDA thing):

1. Kill all Xcode running
2. Delete the app from device (if there is any), Restart your device and disconnect it (if was connected).
3. Open organiser in Xcode and check that device is connected and used for development, if not select "use for development"). Device should be on and connected.
4. Check the signatures are good.
5. Build& run.

This should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Nope it did not help. I have an open bug report with Apple, they are looking into it. In the device logs I have crashlogs of "debigserver".

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this issue for about an hour, trying everything on every post I could find on SO, but nothing worked. I then compared my project settings to another project that did run on iOS and found the issue was MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET was set to 10.7 on the iOS build. I share the same project for my iOS and OSX targets for each app I make, so it's easy to see how this happened. I deleted the setting at the project level, added it to the target level for each OSX target, stripped and built the iOS target and it finally ran! Not to say the other solutions are wrong here, there just could be multiple causes.